# Several Links to the Same URL

Tags: html

I have an HTML file that has several links to the same URL. Is there a way to specify the URL once, instead of in each anchor? Currently, if I change the URL, I manually change it in each anchor. I would consider a Javascript solution, but would prefer something a bit simpler and lightweight. Here is a code sample with two links to google.com:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<P>
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">Preferred search engine</A>
</P>

<HR>
<P>
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">Google</A>
</P>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Using JavaScript would be really bad (imagine if somebody has javascript disabled)

Comment: seriously? js disabled in there days? @paolo.basso99

Comment: if JavaScript is not necessary and in this case the using is just for a development preference why doesn't support that 0.5% of browser that doesn't support JS?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element:

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<base href="https://www.google.com/">
</head>
<body>
<p>
<a href="">Preferred search engine</a>
</p>
<a href="">Google</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Any links you specicfy will be relative to the base URL, so if you had `<a href="foo.html">Preferred search engine</a>` the link would be `https://www.google.com/foo.html`

Comment: And if he has also one internal link?

Comment: @paolo.basso99 He'd just need to use the full URL for that. But that's not is his question is it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javascript to do that. jQuery will do nicely:

```
$(function() {
   $('a').attr('href','https://www.google.com');
});
```

Then you can call the same thing if the URL changed.

If you don't want to use jQuery this is the equivalent js code:

```
<script>
    function ChangeHref(){
       document.getElementById("a").setAttribute("onclick",  "location.href='https://www.google.com'");
    }
</script>
```

You cal trigger the `changehref` from anywhere you want.

BTW: the above function is equal to `document.ready`.